# Find $x$ such that $⌊x⌋>q$ where $q>2$ is a positive integer

Tags: real-analysis

It is just a simple question: Find $x$ such that $⌊x⌋>q$ where $q>2$ is a positive integer. Here $⌊x⌋$ is the integer part of $x$.

Comment: Can't you take a guess?

Comment: $x=q+3145678990$ works.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: Unfotunately, No.

Comment: @I wante a full proof for the range of $x$.

Comment: $[q+1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$q>2$ integer and $q \le x < q+1$ implies $⌊x⌋=q$, can you figure out how $⌊x⌋$ is if $x\ge q+1$?